# Spring configuration doesn't recognise mvc:annotation-driven tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, xml-namespaces

I am not able to use "mvc" namespace in my spring configuration file, for a simple spring mvc based web-application which I am developing.

## Here is the xml snippet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller" annotation-config="true"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/> <-- For this eclipse shows red "*" meaning error

    <bean id="viewResolver1"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/</value> </property>
        <property name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value> </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

It is not recognising the `mvc:annotation-driven` tag, but able to recognise other tags from different namespace, for example `context:annotation-config`.

All this was working fine (I am using Eclipse IDE), only a day before it is giving me this error. I have not changed anything in the environment.

Can anyone please help in how to solve this issue?

Comment: try to Define your tag on top of any other "some other stuff".

Comment: I have added the other details. It was working fine, a day before it started giving issues.

Comment: try to add it before the other tags please.

Comment: If it worked earlier, just restart the eclipse and check ?

Comment: The problem is with your environment (perhaps your eclipse setup), not the config file.  The file works fine when I tested it in my local eclipse Luna.

Comment: The issue got resolved after I restarted the eclipse. Not sure how it helped in resolving the issue. Thanks all for your help.